# One method not seeing another method in the same namespace

Tags: c#

Why do these errors occur, and how can they be fixed?

> Error  1   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\DAL.cs 9   19  EnterData
>
> Error  2   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\DAL.cs 11  54  EnterData
>
> Error  3   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\DAL.cs 25  23  EnterData
>
> Error  4   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\DAL.cs 27  57  EnterData
>
> Error  5   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 208\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\DAL.cs  39  9   EnterData
>
> Error  8   The name 'PopulateMainForm' does not exist in the current context   C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\WebForm1.aspx.cs   25  53  EnterData
>
> Error  9   The name 'PopulateBatchTable' does not exist in the current context C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\WebForm1.aspx.cs   26  50  EnterData
>
> Error  10  The name 'PopulateProblemTable' does not exist in the current context   C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\WebForm1.aspx.cs   27  54  EnterData
>
> Error  11  The name 'PopulateSpecimenTable' does not exist in the current context  C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\WebForm1.aspx.cs   28  56  EnterData

I am keeping the IList classes in a file called DAL.cs in the same directory:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using RadarGraphInsertDLL;

namespace EnterData.DataEntry
{
    public static IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Batch> PopulateBatchTable()
        {
            IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Batch> BatchTable = new IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Batch>();

            try 
            {
            
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            return BatchTable;
        }

        public static IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Problem> PopulateProblemTable()
        {
            IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Problem ProblemTable = new IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Problem();

            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            return ProblemTable;
        }

        public static IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Specimen> PopulateSpecimenTable()
        {
            IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Specimen SpecimenTable = new IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Specimen();

            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

            return SpecimenTable;
        }

        public static LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form PopulateMainForm()
        {
            //populate class
            LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form TheForm = new LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form();

            try
            {
                TheForm.lom_number = lom_numberTextBox.Text.ToInt();
                TheForm.identified_by = identified_byTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.occurrence_date = occurrence_dateTextBox.Text.ToDateTime();
                //TheForm.pre_contact = pre_contactTextBox.Text; //need to create this texdtbox
                //TheForm.pre_practice_code = pre_practice_codeTextBox.Text; //create this
                TheForm.report_by = report_byTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.report_date = report_dateTextBox.Text.ToDateTime();
                TheForm.section_c_comments = section_c_commentsTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.section_c_issue_error_identified_by = section_c_issue_error_identified_byTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.section_d_investigation = section_d_investigationTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.section_e_corrective_action = section_e_corrective_actionTextBox.Text;
                TheForm.section_f_comments = section_f_commentsTextBox.Text;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                
            }

            return TheForm;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't valid.  You cannot declare methods at namespace scope, they must reside in a class (or some other type) definition.

```
namespace EnterData.DataEntry
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public static IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Batch> PopulateBatchTable()
        {
            // code here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: s im sorry can you elaborate, i dont understand

Comment: You cannot declare a method inside of a namespace as you do.  You can only declare types as the error message tells you, i.e., a class, delegate, enum, interface or struct.

Comment: @I__ There is no magic. Just put method in class, not in namespace.

Comment: No problem.  Also, on a side note; the guy currently below me named Eric works on the C# compiler team.  This place is awesome, eh?

Comment: yes pretty awesome. i would pay money to be a member here. but there are too many nerds also

Comment: @I__: If you are never going to instantiate `Foo`, I would recommend using a `static class`.  The program will work either way, but that makes your intentions a little clearer.

Answer (score 4):

DAL.cs has a namespace that directly contains a method declaration. Namespaces may not contain method declarations. Namespaces are allowed to contain classes, delegates, enums, interfaces, structs, or other namespaces. **Hence the error message that a class, delegate, enum, interface or struct was expected.**

What you want is a *static class*:

```
namespace DataEntry
{
     static class MyClass
     {
         public static IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Batch> PopulateBatchTable() 
         { ... }
     }
}
```

and then you call `MyClass.PopulateBatchTable()`.

Comment: why does eric refer to himself in third person in his info?

Comment: Obviously because he's awesome enough to get away with it.

Comment: @I__: What do you propose as an alternative?

Comment: @eric how come you dont ask any questions?

Comment: @I__: First, because when I have a programming problem I don't ask random members of the public for help. I go straight to the document, database or person who can answer my question, because I know what or who that is 90% of the time. Second, because the kind of programming problems I face in my daily work are not amenable to being answered with short answers by people who have not studied the specific problem space.

Answer (score 4):

In DAL.cs you are missing a class declaration:

```
namespace EnterData.DataEntry
{
   public static class DAL // Add Class Here
   {
      public static IList<LOMDLL.Lom_Batch> PopulateBatchTable()
      {
```

Then in your webform, youll need to use the class name to call the static functions

```
...
protected void SubmitData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LOMDLL.Main_Lom_Form MainLomFormTable = DAL.PopulateMainForm(); // Add DAL.
```

Answer (score 1):

One cannot declare functions outside a class definition. What you have done is declare a set of functions without a class definition.

Usually this works with Visual Basic in the form of a module ( in non-.net world).

*Since, I cannot comment on the first answer there I am just posting a new answer.*

Comment: *"One cannot declare functions outside a class definition."* - Certainly you can; you can declare methods in a struct or an interface as well, and you can also declare a delegate type in a namespace.

Comment: May be I should have been more precise. I should have said "define" instead of "declare". Again, that would not include structs.